# Desc LIMIT in Query in Android

Tags: android, mysql

I am trying to get limit of 1000 data from my local DB in my android project. Hence I wrote this query but I get syntax error:

```
int value = 0;
String  updateTime = "0";
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_ALL_DETAILS_LOCAL + " WHERE " + KEY_UPDATE_TIME + " = '"+ updateTime + "'" + " desc LIMIT " + value + ", 1000";
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null
```

ERROR in log

```
 android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "desc": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM AllDetails WHERE updateTime = '0' desc LIMIT 0, 1000
```

I am not sure what is the syntax error here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you are using desc but not specified the field to order by either remove the desc from the query or add some field there.

**1. By removing desc**

```
int value = 0;
String  updateTime = "0";
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_ALL_DETAILS_LOCAL + " WHERE " + KEY_UPDATE_TIME + " = '"+ updateTime + "'" + " LIMIT " + value + ", 1000";
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null)
```

**2. By adding some field.**

```
int value = 0;
String  updateTime = "0";
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_ALL_DETAILS_LOCAL + " WHERE " + KEY_UPDATE_TIME + " = '"+ updateTime + "'" + " order by updateTime  desc LIMIT " + value + ", 1000";
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null
```

Answer (score 2):

you will need to specify a `column` in order to use `desc` so if you want to sort it by using `id` you can write

```
SELECT * FROM AllDetails WHERE updateTime = '0' order by id desc LIMIT 0, 1000
```

You will have to use the `order by` clause to accomplish the same